# Is it possible to insert component selector tags using string interpolation or property binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular2-template

Suppose I have 10 components having the selectors as (had to insert full stops for preventing them from being ommitted )

<.  app-comp1 .>
<. app-comp2 .>
...
<. app-comp10 .>

In the parent component I want to insert only one of the above ten based on a property having the name of the component. Eg. this.component = 'comp7'
So I should only include <. app-comp7 .>

P.s. i know it can be accomplished by ngIf. But that would mean writing 10lines. I need to use shorter code.

Comment: What determines which component is included? What's your criteria?

Comment: I want to have a property / variable. Lets say the variable is compName = 'comp1'. So I was looking for a syntax where I would write in the parent component <.app-{{compName}}.>

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to have dynamic tags in your HTML. You don't necessarily need to have 10 `*ngIf`'s to accomplish this kind of behavior however. Using [`ComponentFactoryResolver`](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver) and an entry component, you can dynamically insert whichever component you want into your DOM.

An example of how this might look:

```
@Component({
  template: `<div #entry></div>`
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild('entry', {read: ViewContainerRef})
  entry: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // Get your component's class here and save it in a variable
    const dynamicComponent = some condition ? ComponentOne : ComponentTwo;
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(dynamicComponent);
    this.entry.createComponent(factory);  
  }  

}
```

Note that this must happen in the [`AfterContentInit` lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Edit: In response to your comment which is that the `ComponentFactoryResolver` is too complex, I would argue it is much simpler than using many `*ngIf` directives. This moves the complexity into a simple function rather than many lines of complex markup. Unfortunately, since you cannot use dynamic HTML tags, these are the two best options for what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you. I already ran into ComponentFactoryResolver while going through the docs but felt it was an overkill for a simple functionality which I mentioned in my question. :(

Comment: Thank you again for the snippet. Your example looks promising. I will give this a try and get back to you.

Comment: Happy to help :) - let me know if you need more information